# Getting NoSuch Element Exception in Selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have a Tab called Information .i need to click on Information Tab.
 the same xpath is working for other scenario Which has same information tab with same html code  When i Am trying use that xpath in other scenario getting no Such Element Found Exception.

Please help me to resolve this issue

xpath :

```
xpath=//h3[text()='Information']
```

HTML :

```
<div class="header" >
    <h3>
    <i class="icon icon-openclose"/>
    Information
    </h3>
```

Comment: I have used below solutions: 1.Increasing wait Time 2.Using Explicit wait

Comment: Are you sure that italic node appears as self-closing child of `h3` when page rendered or it actually looks like `<h3>
    <i class="icon icon-openclose">
    Information</i>
    </h3>`?

Comment: Yes.<h3>
<i class="icon icon-openclose"/>
Information
</h3>

Comment: OK, so text appears not in Italic style ( ` *"Information"* ` ) but as usual (`"Information"`), right?

Comment: Yes.it wont appear in Italic

Answer (score 1):

1.Try by giving some wait time before click "Information" tab.

2.Make sure it comes under the frame or not.

3.Analyse the page HTML code that it does not have the same h3 with information text.

Comment: 1.Try by giving some wait time before click "Information" tab. --Tried 2..Make sure it comes under the frame or not.---I am switching to frame also 3.Analyse the page HTML code that it does not have the same h3 with information text.---It has only one match

Answer (score 1):

As per the *HTML* you have shared if you observe the text **Information** , it is within the `<h3>` tag. So you can use `xpath` as :

```
//h3[normalize-space()='Information']
```